# PL/SQL Trigger to update another table only upon INSERT of specific record on one table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789497/3317808) that update triggers on every insert on `tableA`.

---

Scenario is,

In `tableA`, we have `WATERMARK_FLAG` column of type `CHAR(1)` with possible values `Y` or `N`

In `tableB`, we have `PROCESSED_FLAG` column of type `CHAR(1)` with possible values `Y` or `N`

There is no primary key - foreign key relation between two tables

Primary key columns are same in both tables

PK(col_1, col_3, col_4)

---

On `INSERT` of record in `tableA` with `WATERMARK_FLAG` as `Y` update `PROCESSED_FLAG` with `Y` in all rows of `tableB`

How to provide PL/SQL trigger syntax for specific `INSERT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_tableA
  BEFORE INSERT ON bi_tableA
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (WATERMARK_FLAG = 'Y')
DECLARE
BEGIN
  UPDATE tableB
  SET PROCESSED_FLAG = 'Y';
END bi_tableA;
/
```

However, the performance could decrease. But I assume this is just an exercise.

Comment: Why would the performance decrease?

Comment: We will use it in production

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW` means the trigger will fire and evaluate the `WHEN` condition for every row that is inserted, as opposed to only firing once for an entire bulk operation.

Comment: It fires for every row thus it will update the same again and again. In terms of performance a compound trigger would be better, it can update only once.

Comment: Why would it update again and again(frequently)? It should update tableB every 15 mins, because every 15 min,  record  is inserted with column(`WATERMARK_FLAG` ) value `Y` in tableA

Comment: In this case the performance is not relevant.